# WKWebView causes memory warning and the app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, memory, wkwebview, browser-cache

I have a simple app with a WKWebView. When running on iOS 9, the memory usage stays around 5 Mb with is expected since WKWebView runs in a separate process. But memory usage for "other processes" goes high after a couple of navigations, especially on heavy pages. When the memory usage reaches its threshold, the app gets two memory warnings and then gets terminated. `webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate` is never called.

I've tried to respond to `didReciveMemoryWarning`in a couple of ways with no success. This is what I have tried:

```swift
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   print("**** MEMORY WARNING! ****")
   URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
   URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
   URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
}
```

```swift
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   print("**** MEMORY WARNING! ****")
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
            WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
                records.forEach { record in
                    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
                    print("[WebCacheCleaner] Record \(record) deleted")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is my code:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MyAwsomeWebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var page:WKWebView! = WKWebView()

    @IBOutlet weak var WKBaseView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        page.navigationDelegate = self
        if let url = URL(string: "https://hitta.se") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            page.load(request)
        }

    }

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = page
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        print("**** MEMORY WARNING! ****")
    }

    func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        print("*** Terminate WebView Process ***")
    }


}
```

How can I clear my WKWebViews memory usage when I receive a memory warning so that the app won't crash?

Comment: Can you put `deinit { print("controller deinitialized") }` line into your `MyAwsomeWebViewController`? And then please run the app and open screens in application -include `MyAwsomeWebViewController`. And then check the console and find `"controller deinitialized"`  text. If you can not find text it is means you have a retain cycle. Comment all initialized objects and run again, open comments one by one and run again. Check `"controller deinitialized"` text on console every time. Where you opened the comment as soon as you saw the text did not come that's where the retain cycle starts.

Comment: `Retain Cycle` causes `Memory Leak` and I think your problem is causes `Memory Leak`

Comment: I've created a view controller that segues to `MyAwsomeWebViewController` and I've added the `deinit` function. When I close `MyAwsomeWebViewController` everything works fine and I get `"controller deinitialized"`. The memory is cleared. However, this doesn't solve my problem since I don't want to deinit my ViewContoler every time I load a page.

Comment: can you try and load the same page in safari mobile browser and check how it reacts, usually if you are loading heavy objects in your web application and trying to load the same page in the mobile browser it's going to be painful as CPU resources in desktop is greater than the mobile CPU. Have you identified what actions you do in the webpage causes the spike in memory warning? @MartinClaesson

Comment: Yes, I have tried to load the page in safari. It sometimes shows an error message and reloads the page. This is the behavior I’m looking for. I don’t want it to crash my app. From what I read about wkwebview it shouldn’t crash the app if it runs out of memory. It should kill the wkwebview and trigger webViewContentProcessDidTerminate.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView is only available for iOS 8 and above. I tested your code with Xcode 10.2.1 and the memory works fine while navigate through the WebView.

Updated: Right @Martin Claesson

Comment: WKWebVIew is supported since iOS 8. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview